# Compression algorithms for Strings

Tags: algorithm, string, compression, qr-code

I have to generate QRCodes using concatenated object properties. These strings might be long, that's why I'd like to know which compression algorithm to use knowing that my String's length is between 25 an 100+ characters

thanks in advance,

Jerec

Comment: Which characters can appear in your string?

Comment: are object properties from a limited set? if so it might be a lot better to use IDs for them instead of the long strings. IDs can be compressed further but using them could grant the most benefits in the first place

Comment: the object properties are limited, but there can be an unlimited amount of objects. Indeed I will store IDs and maybe one Double

Comment: Could you give examples of such QRCode-Strings?

Comment: Here is an example : 14523;67548;46578;22164;78425;46167;6;17962;449,4 so 6 IDs, the number of IDs displayed before, another id and a price. I used ";" as aseparator, but if anything is better, let me know ;)     ps: sry for not having replied earlier and thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that since you are going to use compression before you store the strings that these QR codes will not be readable by any client, it would have to be an application that you wrote (b/c you are storing character with an unknown encoding, the client won't be able to decode).

Instead of compressing and storing the long string in the QR code, have your application create a [URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) (like a [GUID](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier&ei=1hLcTcuWOqrb0QGutpH9Dw&usg=AFQjCNG8ACp9GO_beQ2Nw1FXitJ3UuWqQQ&sig2=wouzRgiawqrQRS1FfVd44A) or a URL) and when your application decodes that [URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) it looks up all the values (uncompressed) that you wanted to store in the QR code.  Then your app can just look up the format in any way it wants.

For example, assuming your persistant storage is an xml file, but it could be anything:

```
<URI = "http://mydomain.com/790C9704-8C61-435F-991D-CDBB5767AA3D">
    <MyElement>14523</MyElement>
    <MyElement>67548</MyElement>
    ...
    <MyElement>46167</MyElement>
</URI>
```

Encoded on QR code: "http://mydomain.com/790C9704-8C61-435F-991D-CDBB5767AA3D", values can then be looked up.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I think that if I stored the information the way you proposed and that I have around 30+ 5-digits elements, the resolution of the QRcode will be higher than usual, but if I rise the error correction level there should not be any problem

Comment: Just make sure that you are encoding a fixed width URI that points to your actual data.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm used to encode QR codes is dependent on the type of data you encode. See http://www.swetake.com/qr/qr1_en.html.

If you know, for example, that you always have the same number of digits per id and therefor could just string them together without punctuation, you can encode them as purely numeric and you'll use 10 bits for every three characters.

If you need some kind of separator, if you use something in "0-9A-Z $%*+-./:", you'll stay alphanumeric and get 2 characters in 11 bits.

If you give it arbitrary data (note that this includes any lower case: the list above does not include lower case letters) you're going to be using 8 bits per characters.

So numeric only would end up being 60% smaller.